# Adding a line to a file

Tags: c#, list, addition, contains

I have this code:

```
List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
in j = 0;
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

lineList = theFinalList.Select( line =>
{
     if (line.PartDescription != "")
         return line.PartDescription + " " + line.PartNumber + " " + line.TapeWidth + "\n";
     else
         return "N/A " + line.PartNumber + " " + line.TapeWidth + "\n";
})
.Where(x => !(x.Contains("FID") || x.Contains("EXCLUDE")))
.ToList();

foreach (string word in lineList)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
        dictionary[word]++;
    else
        dictionary[word] = 1;
}

var ordered = from k in dictionary.Keys
              orderby dictionary[k] descending
              select k;

foreach (string key in ordered)
{
    var splitKey = key.Split(' ');
    if (!splitKey[2].Contains("8"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 \"\" \"\" \"\" 0 0 0 0 0 0 )", j);
        j++;
    }

    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"\" {3} 0 0 0 0 0 )",
                               j, splitKey[0], splitKey[1], dictionary[key]));
    j++;
}
```

An example of this output looks like this (assuming all of the `line.TapeWidth`'s do **NOT** contain "8"):

```
( 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "136380" "" 18 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "128587" "" 41 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 3 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "138409" "" 11 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "110984" "" 8 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "3216R_1.3" "114441" "" 6 0 0 0 0 0 )
```

### HOWEVER

I would like to change it so if the `!line.TapeWidth.Contains("8")` then I would like to output an extra line.. Let's say that the line that contained `"138409"` and `"114441"` both had a `TapeWidth` that was **not equal** to **8**. so the ***NEW*** output would look like this:

```
( 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "136380" "" 18 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "128587" "" 41 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 3 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "138409" "" 11 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "2125R_1.0" "110984" "" 8 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 6 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 7 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "3216R_1.3" "114441" "" 6 0 0 0 0 0 )
```

### So

I am trying to insert that "blank" line **BEFORE** the other line is printed off...

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: This seems like a simple logic modification.  As asked, you're just trying to get us to write your code for you.  There is no attempt at solving the problem shown here.  What have you tried?  What is going wrong?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: I tried: `else if (!(line.TapeWidth.Contains("8"))) { reutnr "" + "" + "\n"; }` between the first if/else loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an easy way to do it, just check for the condition before you print the line.

```
foreach (string key in ordered)
{
    var splitKey = key.Split(' ');
    if (!splitKey[1].Contains("8")) {
        sw.WriteLine("( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 )", j);
        j++;
    }
    sw.WriteLine(
        "( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"\" {3} 0 0 0 0 0 )",
        j, splitKey[0], splitKey[1], dictionary[key]);
    j++;
}
```